# Where should this application be registered?

Tags: azure-active-directory

This [MS Tutorial Registering SPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa#register-the-spa-application) missing this piece. What's the difference

[image]

Comment: Can you please elloborate your issue what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT While I's trying to register a SPA got this prompt. We log in to Portal under an account which has one or more subscription, a directory is under a subscription. I'd like to know what `Only associate with personal account` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   The documentation you are referring to is regarding the registration of a ***‘Single Page Application (SPA)’*** in Azure AD B2C. Thus, it directly refers to registering the application in an Azure AD B2C tenant/directory. The documentation doesn’t state where to register the application in Azure AD B2C because it considers that the sign into the Azure AD B2C tenant is through a local Azure AD B2C account or a work/school account and not through a social account or a private/personal account.

•   You are getting that option because maybe you are registering your first application in that Azure AD B2C tenant/directory. As when you create a new Azure AD B2C tenant with a free tier Azure AD subscription and register your first application, you get that prompt to confirm where to associate your application with.

•   Also, it might be because you are signed into the Azure AD B2C tenant with **a user account who was invited to sign up into Azure AD B2C** or **the user has been created using his personal/public email ID in the tenant** and the **user signed up with his personal/social email ID account**. Due to which, he has been **granted privileges to register an application** in that Azure AD B2C tenant and when you (that user) tried to register an application, you are getting that prompt asking whether to register that application in Azure AD B2C directory or associate it with that account with which you have logged in to the Azure AD B2C directory. Thus, this pop up in your case. For more information, you can refer to the link below which describes the account types in Azure AD B2C: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technical-overview#accounts-in-azure-ad-b2c

Comment: I have a free-tier (MS) account and register my first application, It is the 2nd option listed in your answer. Selecting `Register in this directory` seems working. I'd like to know the consequences/impact if selecting `Only associate with personal account`. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, if you select the option for `Only associate with personal account`, then that application registered will be available only for that user logged in with the personal account. It will not be shown in `App registrations` for other users unless it is assigned to them. Kindly refer to this documented FAQ link for more details regarding this: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#which-social-identity-providers-do-you-support-now--which-ones-do-you-plan-to-support-in-the-future-

Comment: Quote _that application registered will be available only for that user logged in with the personal account_  means only that user can log into that app?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that only that user will be able to log into that app, but it means that when that user logs into the Azure AD B2C portal, that application will be available only for him to manage unless and until that user adds an owner to that app or assigns that app to more users. For assigning an app to more users, please refer to this link below: - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-assign-users#assign-a-user-account-to-an-enterprise-application. Also, that app as it is registered in Azure AD B2C, will be a customer facing app.

Comment: Thus, anyone who encounters the published link of the app can login using Azure AD B2C and use the services provided by it.